# Little Pictures

Tags: visual, rebus, english

Today I've decided to make puzzles using images because that's easier for me to do than think of a sub-par riddle. A note about these: no, they do not necessarily pertain to a famous saying. Rather, they are simple sentences or phrases about something. There isn't anything hidden in the image hex or bit-wise; what you see is what you need.
I hope these ones are pretty easy! I plan to make more complicated ones down the line.


1: Found by **Zimonze**
2: Found by **El-Guest**
3: Found by **El-Guest**

Hints Found for 2:

> The fruit in the basket aren't the focus of that picture; what's happening to the number of items? Is that something on the bee's head? That man's proportions are off!

Hints Found for 3:

> The cross-out only pertains to the word it is on. There's nothing *clever* about it! The hat should only be worn by the ace. What do you see staring back at you?

Formal Hint 1:

> The third image in 3 is not an iphone; what's important about it is what you see looking into it. The first image is something most people don't have in their yards anymore.

There are three to solve:

[image: picture puzzles]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 is

> "Little more than a bee sting"

3 is

> "Well aren't you a winner?"

Comment: Are the references for the third one correct? Or am I totally on the wrong track? (And same for the second one with the exception of the fruit)

Comment: Okay I think I got the 2nd one...the 3rd one I feel I'm a little farther away...

Comment: 2nd is perfect :) Credited at the top until the third is found. 3: these parts are correct (lbh/frys, svefg). "Hint 1" was updated with a tidbit about the first image. What's happening to the "are"? There is no blending of words between pictures for this one.

Comment: Is the first picture supposed to be a rot13(fjvat)?

Comment: Well... you are indeed! Congrats on solving the second and third :) Big thanks to Zimonze for finding the answer to the first!

Comment: Thanks very much! This was a brain stretcher but lots of fun! Can't wait to see what the harder ones look like! :)

Answer (score 3):

For #1:

> Crocodile leaves to neverland ?
>  Because
>  Croc+dial, leave, two, neverland

Comment: Correct! Maybe you can find the other two? The "proper" sentence I guess is rot13(Gur pebpbqvyr rfpncrf (be rfpncrq) gb Arireynaq.)